# Set a default parameter by name when calling a method in Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

**Background:**

I know that in `Python` you can set a value of a default parameter by using the name of the parameter when calling the method.
Here's a quick example of what that looks like in `Python` (with the results):

```
def do_something(first, second=2, third=3):
    print(first, second, third)

do_something(1)             // (1, 2, 3)
do_something(1, 22)         // (1, 22, 3)
do_something(1, None, 33)   // (1, None, 33)
do_something(1, third=33)   // (1, 2, 33)
```

**Actual question:**

How can I send a value for a default parameter in `Javascript` using the name (and not the location) of the parameter?

So far, I have found that you can:

1. Send `undefined` values for the parameters you don't want to change until you get to the position of the parameter you do want to change.
2. Change the function itself to receive an object and then send an object to the function (as described [here](http://jimrottinger.github.io/named-arguments-using-es6-destructuring/)).

Does anyone know of a way this can be done using the name of the parameter like the `Python` example above?

Comment: No, that is not possible, and the alternatives you list apply.

Comment: not possible, and best is `do_something(1, undefined, 33)`